# iOS Launch image stretching for half-second

Tags: ios

My game is landscape only and on both the iPad and iPhone, when I launch the game, the launch image is stretched like it's being fit into portrait mode. This only last for about 1/2 second, then it displays correctly for the rest of the time. I can't figure out how to get it to display correctly from the start.  It's only a 1/2 second and then it fixes itself, so it's not a massive issue, it just looks unprofessional.

Having the device locked (or unlocked) to landscape doesn't change the behavior.

I have this Info.plist key set: `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`

I have the following images and they are all in landscape (wider than tall)

```
Default-568h@2x.png
Default-667h@2x.png
Default-736h@3x.png
Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
Default-Landscape~ipad.png
```

I'm not (and can't, without a lot of work) use  Storyboards.

Comment: are you adding launch screen on UIImageView in appDelegate ? if no then problem is in your launch screen size.

Comment: Any way you can share a portion of your project we can look at? Or recreate in a different project and share that?

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't seem to be using storyboards I can only advice you to check what interface is your app being launched at.

Ensure that you only have Landscape Left and Landscape Right under your target configuration.

(Select your project) -> **Targets** -> (Select your target) -> **General** **Tab** -> **Deployment Info** -> (there you will find **Device Orientation**)

Also make sure that under the Info.plist, under the key "Supported interface orientations" the "portrait" one is not included.

Comment: Yeah, all that is set. Here is by plist file.

[image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dziyjze2c8rwxaa/my_plist.png?dl=0)

Comment: Have you tried adding the "-Landscape" modifier to your launch image? You can attach more than one modifier, like this: Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png